# Developing Cross-platform "Low-Level" Software with .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, cross-platform

I know it might seem like a broad question, but I really couldn't find anything (either encouraging or discouraging) about this. Does it make sense to develop applications that need a lot of native OS calls and access to hardware resources with .Net Core? I'm referring to software like antivirus, screen recorder, hardware health report, etc.

The main reason to have that idea is cross-platform development and expertise of the team in .Net Core. If not, what will be your suggested technology to adopt?

Comment: You'll have to address this on a case by case basis, figure out what core can do for you, and what it cant, and whether its worth while to develop a native app, also yes its bordering on too broad

Comment: @TheGeneral we know that we can do many things with P/Invoke. Basically, it means that we can call any OS api on Windows, Mac and Linux (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop). I want to make sure that we won't end up rewriting the whole thing in, say, Go because .Net Core was not designed to do it in first place.

Comment: I understand your concern and as annoying as this answer is, you really have to do research, if you have to pinvoke the whole app are you going to be happy, is it going to be worth while, do you like .net core. do you need to interact as part of the kernel. To answer your question, no it is probably not worth while to write a virus scanner in .net core. the more low-level you go the less its not feasible. However that's not to say its impossible. however i truly do think you have answered your own questions and only you know what your projects are and their domain, and whats involved